# Slide listview down/up to hiding/showing Listview Animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to make an animation like WordBrain App. But i have no keyword/way about this animation.
Could anyone help me, pls?

Here is image animation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz6Vr.jpg

Comment: can you please go through: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: i mean showing/hiding animation, not scrolling animation.